# Wie heißt der durch den Vater gebrochene Kinderarm?

Tags: single-word-request

Kinder gehen oft an der Hand ihrer Eltern. Wenn die Kinder stolpern, ziehen viele Eltern ihre Kinder ruckartig hoch. Das ist meistens hilfreich gemeint, führt aber nicht selten dazu, dass den Kindern das Schultergelenk ausgekugelt oder gar der Arm gebrochen wird. Es gibt sogar ein Wort für einen so entstandenen Armbruch.

Welches?

(Nein, das ist kein Ratespiel. Ich habe vor Jahren mal einen Artikel darüber gelesen, dort wurde der medizinische Fachbegriff genannt. Leider habe ich ihn vergessen. Ich dachte, er laute *Vaterarm* oder so ähnlich, aber ich finde unter diesem Begriff nichts hierzu. Vielleicht weiß von euch jemand weiter?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich denke, du meinst das hier:

[https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiusköpfchen-Subluxation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiusk%C3%B6pfchen-Subluxation)

> Kindermädchen-Ellenbogen

oder

> Sonntagsarm

Comment: Die direkte Übersetzung des _Nursemaid's Elbow_ ist im Deutschen aber unbekannt. Es bleibt eigentlich nur der Fachausdruck.